# UICollectionView two cells in a single row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to layout a vertical scrolling collection view cells to layout like this

[image: Layout]

When I tried to size the cells like that it made the bottom right one go onto the next line instead of group them together.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `UICollectionViewLayout` class. There you should find methods you need to achieve your desired look.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html